# Exceptions in downloading htmlunit

Tags: java, download, htmlunit

I am in the process of downloading and using htmlunit for Java. I installed the 2.27 version (I believe this is the latest version) as a jar file and expanded it. The code is riddled with lines that cause compiler exceptions such as the following.

```
//Code from the WebClient class
//The switch statement has the error according to the compiler.
public WebResponse loadWebResponse(WebRequest webRequest)
    throws IOException
  {
    String str;

    switch ((str = webRequest.getUrl().getProtocol()).hashCode()) {case 3076010:  if (str.equals("data")) {} break; case 3143036:  if (str.equals("file")) break;  case 92611469:  if ((goto 107) && (str.equals("about")))
      {
        return makeWebResponseForAboutUrl(webRequest.getUrl());


        return makeWebResponseForFileUrl(webRequest);


        return makeWebResponseForDataUrl(webRequest);
      }
      break; }
    return loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(webRequest, 20);
  }
```

Has anyone else had this problem? If so, how did you deal with it?

(Ps. I'm sorry for the real long line; I wanted to keep it formatted the same was as in the original code)

Comment: This seems like an "un-compiled" version of a previously compiled code... The `String` based `switch` is using `hashcode()` internally, but if i remember correctly, there should be 2 `switch`es in the internal implementation...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Hmm, I'm not sure I fully understand. Wouldn't that mean that all the lines would have errors? I honestly don't know.

Comment: And how exactly did you tried to "downloading an using" **HtmlUnit**?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I went to the htmlunit home page and went to the download section. It was a link to Source Forge. I selected the 2.27 folder and downloaded the jar file. I then expanded it. I imported this class (in my program), and an error in this class showed up. I tried other classes, but they had errors too. Did I download bad code?

Comment: What do you mean by "imported this class"?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto  import extensions.htmlunitPack.com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these steps:

1. Go to http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/
   Under **Where to find...** click the link below **Latest release**
2. Click on the file link that ends with **.bin.zip**
   After downloading, extract all files to a folder, keeping the folder hierarchy.
3. Add all the **JAR** files found at the `/lib` sub-folder to your Java project's CLASSPATH.
4. Import classes, like this:
   `import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebCli‌​ent;`

Comment: I just tried this, but importing the classes isn't the problem. It gives me syntax errors on some lines (like the line in the code I gave). I don't know if I downloaded a wrong version or something.

Comment: What **Java** version are you using to compile? And show us the code that get syntax errors...

Comment: Java 8 -- As I said, there are scatterings of lines with syntax errors, too many to show all of them. The code I put has one in the switch statement line.

Comment: I do not know where do you got that code, as there is no such code in the library... Look at lines 1307 - 1322 in https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.java

Comment: That is so strange. I didn't change the code from what I downloaded, but that code in the link you sent doesn't match. Thank you for your help; I think that will lead me to the answer.

Comment: I think you downloaded the binary version, and somehow ended up using it disassembled...